# C Implementation of Lists

Tags: c, list, pointers

I am using the following code to implement my own version of lists as to help me understand and grasp the concept of pointers. But this code is buggy and I can't figure out what's wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int n;
    struct node* next;
} node;

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    node item;
    item.n = 0;
    item.next = NULL;
    node* list = &item;
    node* new_node = NULL;
    node* old_node = &item;

    while (1 == 1)
    {
        // get int from user
        scanf("%i", &i);

        if (i < 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Create new node
            node new_item;
            new_node = &new_item;

            // Set the value of new node
            new_node->n = i;
            new_node->next = NULL;

            // Point old node to new node
            old_node->next = new_node;

            // Swap nodes
            old_node = new_node;
            new_node = NULL;
        }

    }

    // Print the list
    node* pointer = list;
    int count = 1;
    while (pointer->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("Item %i %p: %i\n", count, pointer, pointer->n);
        pointer = pointer->next;
        getchar();
    }
}
```

I am using the above code to create my own implementation for lists. The problem is when I try to print out the list, It goes into an infinite loop. Can anyone point out where I went wrong?

Comment: Building a linked list with no dynamic allocation? `node new_item;  new_node = &new_item;` Um.... Do you know what [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) and [`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) are used for?  Time to learn how to use a [*debugger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger).

Comment: OMG while (1 == 1) ? use while(1)

Comment: ooooh....I thought that wouldn't be needed.

Comment: how to use `malloc()` and `free()` in this code?

Comment: Read the documentation I linked. It has examples. And seriously. Start honing debugging skills. You'll spend half your professional career on the business end of a debugger (and only that much if you're very, *very*, good.

Comment: you need to know how local variables are implemented in C. you are basically keep reusing the same object.

Comment: @WhozCraig is `node new_item = malloc(sizeof(node));` ok?

Comment: @WhozCraig and using `free(new_item)` at the end of loop?

Comment: if your intention is to not use malloc/free then you should update the question.

Comment: I've answered my question using some code I wrote which worked. Can you please tell me if my code is "good"?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be attempting to build a forward-chained linked list while preserving the order of insertion. The most glaring problems in your code are:

- Infinite while-loop condition
- Using automatic variables in your list for what should be dynamic nodes.

Both of these are mandatory to address. The former is addressed by simply modifying the while-loop to (a) check the result of the `scanf` execution (which you should *always* do), and (b), check the range of `i`. Thus,

```
while (scanf("%i", &i) == 1 && i >= 0)
{
     ... use i here
}
```

Regarding the second problem, that gets more cumbersome. Dynamic allocation using memory management functions `malloc` and `free` are probably in order. An implementation that does this *and* utilizes a pointer-to-pointer to make the forward-chaining trivial is presented below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int n;
    struct node* next;
} node;

int main()
{
    // builds the list. uses a pointer-to-pointer that holds
    //  the address of the next pointer to populate wih a
    //  dynamic node allocation. initially it holds the
    //  addres of our list head pointer.

    node *list = NULL;  // list head pointer
    node **pp = &list;
    int i;

    while (scanf("%i", &i) == 1 && i >= 0)
    {
        *pp = malloc(sizeof **pp);
        if (*pp == NULL)
        {
            perror("Failed to allocate node");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        (*pp)->n = i;
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    }
    *pp = NULL; // terminates the list with NULL next value

    // print the list
    const node* pointer = list;
    for (i=1; pointer; ++i)
    {
        printf("Item %i %p: %i\n", i, pointer, pointer->n);
        pointer = pointer->next;
    }

    // free the list
    while (list)
    {
        void *victim = list;
        list = list->next;
        free(victim);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Sample Input**

```
1 3 2 4 3 5 -1
```

**Sample Output**

```
Item 1 0x100300000: 1
Item 2 0x100300010: 3
Item 3 0x100300020: 2
Item 4 0x100300030: 4
Item 5 0x100300040: 3
Item 6 0x100300050: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

There's more to say here, but fundamentally: you have only allocated one `node`, and it's on the stack.  It's declared inside the `else` clause.  Since there's only one of them allocated, you've set its next pointer to effectively point back to itself.  Hence, the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#include<malloc.h>

struct node
{

int info;

struct node *next;

};

struct node *first,*temp,*start;

int item;
struct node *insertatend(struct node *,int);

main()
{
       char ch;   
    first=NULL;
     while(ch=='y'){
           printf("Enter the item");
           scanf("%d",&item);
           first=insertatend(first,item);
        printf("Do you want to continue press y");
        scanf("%c",&ch);
}

/*Insert item in linked list at the end*/
struct node *insertatend(struct node *first,int x)
{
   start=first;
   struct node *new;
   new=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));   
   new->info=x;
   new->next=NULL;
        if(first==NULL)
            {
            first=new;  
                }
            else
            {
                temp=first;
                while(temp->next!=NULL)
                    {
                    temp=temp->next;    
                    }
                    temp->next=new;

            }

 return(first);
}
```

or if you want to go with your cod so use while(1) instead of 1==1 because its always true you never come out from loop.
 Hope it will for you

Answer (score 0):

Since you are OK using pointers with malloc & free I recommend the below:
This should satisfy your question. Let me know if you have any qns.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct Node
{
  int a;
  Node *next;
}NODEType;

NODEType *head = NULL;

int printtraverse()
{
  NODEType *n = head;
  while ( n !=NULL ) {
    printf ( "item = %d \n", n->a );
    n = n->next;
  }
}

int main ()
{
  int t=0;
  NODEType *curr=NULL;
  while (1) {
    scanf("%d",&t);

  NODEType *n = (NODEType *) malloc (sizeof (NODEType));
  n->a = t;
  n->next = NULL;

  if ( head == NULL )
  {
     head = n;
     curr = n;
  } else {
     curr->next = n;
     curr = n;
  }   

 if ( t == -1 )
    printtraverse();

 }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code worked!! It seems like i `malloc()` and `free()` did the trick. Thanks for the help all! And please point out any flaws in this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int n;
    struct node* next;
} node;

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    // pointer to start of list
    node* list = NULL;
    // nodes to keep track
    node* old_node = NULL;
    node* new_node = NULL;

    while (scanf("%i", &i) == 1 && i >= 0)
    {
        if (old_node == NULL)
        {
            // create new node
            new_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
            new_node->n = i;
            new_node->next = NULL;

            // point list to this node
            list = new_node;

            // point old node to this node
            old_node = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            // create new node
            new_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
            new_node->n = i;
            new_node->next = NULL;

            // point old nodes pointer to this node
            old_node->next = new_node;

            // set the new node as old node
            old_node = new_node;
        }
    }

    // print the list
    node* pointer = list;
    int count = 1;
    while (pointer != NULL)
    {
        printf("Node %i : %i\n", count, pointer->n);
        free(pointer);
        pointer = pointer->next;
        count++;
    }
}
```